# Quering integer in MySQL over PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, integer

I'm working with a table ("Item") which has the field "Aprovado" and it's an integer that checks if the item is approved or not (1 for yes, 0 for no) (not my table, I would have chosen proper boolean).

I know there are items there, and I know there are lots of items with "Aprovado" set to 1. (I am successful with queries "SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY ItemID ASC")

yet, when I do:

```
mysql_select_db($theDatabase, $db) or die("Could not find database."); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM Item WHERE Aprovado = 1";
$resultID = mysql_query($query, $db) or die("Data not found.");
```

It just returns "Data not Found." What's wrong?

Comment: We need more than that to debug. Does this query for on mysql client? Also show the $db

Comment: Could you show the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE Item` in your question?

Comment: are you sure that there is data with field value Aprovado=1, and its an integer. just check Aprovado='1'

Comment: Use mysql_error() to check for any errors.

Comment: Have you tried the same query outside of PHP?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there is data with field value Aprovado=1. This PHP is a new version of an old one which outputed everything relevant to an xml (and there are tons of Aprovado 1). And i've also tried ='1' with no luck. Now i'm gonna do : die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); as Eljakim suggested

Comment: the error was on another part of the code, Eljakim's suggestion allowed me to find the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try changing your die(...) into:

> die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

That will show you the actual MySQL error.

Comment: thanks +1 very useful (I hope it's gonna be) going to do that now.

Comment: marked as answer as this was the bit of code that allowed me to find the problem (it wasn't on the above pasted code, it was on another point... But as every die was returning "Data not found" i didn't knew.) i'm adopting showing the actual error from now on

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query does not return FALSE if the query returns no data. It only returns false on an error condition:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   die("Data not found");
}
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$resultID = $row['resultID'];
```